# Controlando o intervalo de plot do matplotlib , problema de uso de 100% da memória ram

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ciência-de-dados

Olá comunidade do Stackoverflow :)

Estou desenvolvendo um código pequeno que plote o gráfico a partir de 2 listas preenchidas a partir de uma equação enquanto uma condição while não estiver satisfeita.

Assim que as listas estão preenchidas, eu uso o matplotlib para plotar o gráfico bidimensional com os valores extraídos, porém são muitos valores e eu gostaria de saber se dá pra plotar apenas pontos em intervalos específicos, porque se eu plotar todos, o uso de memória do meu PC sobe a 100% e o Python trava e dá memory error. Teria uma forma de otimizar esse processo?

Por exemplo, usando o intervalo de um em um nanometro (que é o caso que estou tentando resolver)

```
# Modelando a energia do fóton em uma equação

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

h = 1.05457168 * 10**(-34) # J * s
c = 299792458.0 #m/s
i = 0.000004 #metros
energias =[] 
wavelenghts=[]


while (i!=0.000007):
    E = (h*c)/i
    energias.append(E)
    wavelenghts.append(i)
    i=i+0.000001

print (energias)
print (wavelenghts)

plt.plot (energias, wavelenghts, color='blue', marker = 'o', linestyle = 'solid')
```

Comment: vc pode usar um for para definir um intervalo para o calculo

Comment: Como? :( Pensei q cairia no mesmo problema, devido a quantidade de algarismos entre os valores.

Comment: onosendai ja corrijiu seu script com o minimo de esforço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o problema seja com a precisão da variável. Altere a linha 12 de

```
while (i!=0.000007):
```

para

```
while (i<=0.000007): # menor ou igual a 0.000007
```

O comentário abaixo de @EltonNunes é perfeito. Apenas complementando: comparações de inequalidade (`!=`) são problemáticas quando utilizando operações de ponto flutuante dada a imprecisão à medida em que cálculo involve mais e mais casas decimais em consequência da especificação [IEEE-754](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Uma outra maneira de evitar este comportamento seria mantendo o seu laço com uma variável inteira, preservando assim o comportamento esperado pela comparação de inequalidade:

```
i = 4 #metros
[...]

while (i!=7):
    vi = i/1000000
    E = (h*c)/vi
    energias.append(E)
    wavelenghts.append(vi)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Consegui, funcionou! Mas porque isso aconteceu? :o

Comment: vc colocou para que seja diferente de 7e-6, o loop vai esperar exatamente isso, ou seja se for um valor maior ou menos, ele não vai parar, a correção foi calcular equanto i seja menor, operações aritimeticas de numeros fracionarios casa uma variação minuscula que atrapalha a exatidão

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado !

Comment: Olá, OnoSendai, para não gerar esse problema seria interessante, porém esse código é justamente para problemas físicos e eu achei isso sensacional pois acabou que minha pergunta acabou servindo para o caso em que a inequalidade no código não permitia operar os valores float, eu imaginava que se eu controlasse o número de casas decimais isso não aconteceria, mas não era o caso. 

E pra falar a verdade, os valores 0.000004 e 0.000007 se tratam das energias associadas aos fótons de comprimento de onda que estão no intervalo visível ao olho humano, por isso são esses valores. o/